# How to easily develop android UI?

Tags: android, uikit

Is there an easy way to develop UI in android?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300014/tools-for-rapid-layout-interface-creations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help all of us.[android ui builder](http://www.droiddraw.org/)

Comment: That's a bit outdated in 2010. Use the inbuilt Editor or App Inventor.

Comment: @pentium10 hard to find download link for app inventor..

Comment: App Inventor is an online product.

Comment: @Pentium10, Outdated? I think you meant to say not mature enough yet. I did check out DroidDraw six months ago, and it definitely wasn't mature enough yet. As to App Inventor, it's not written in Java (it's written in Scheme/LISP) and the creators of App Inventor have no intention of changing the scope of their project and letting us access the ascii source code anyway (to them, the source code is the drawings).

Comment: http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/