# Tools for rapid layout/interface creations?

Tags: java, android

Does anyone know of any tools (besides DroidDraw) that can help me create the basics of my projects a bit quicker? I'm looking for something that will allow me to very quickly generate the XML for my layouts so I don't have to sit there typing like a robot for so long.

Thanks!

Comment: I would especially like to see something that "encourages" best practices as well.  Maybe we should start an open-source one?

Comment: I'm down. Let's talk. Though, I'm learning that the layout resource editor makes life a lot easier. But still....also there is this: http://www.amlcode.com/examples/

Comment: Maybe you need more practice. Writing a simple layout could take 2 minutes (1 minute using DroidDraw). Writing a complex layout could take 10 minutes which is actually not that bad. Creating a complex layout using DroidDraw is the hell... there's nothing better than knowing what you are doing and writing clean XML. Maybe there isn't any other tool for that better than DroidDraw, because I think it does not work the effort to do one (not for building mobile UI). Finally, if you take more than one hour writing a layout: you are too slow or your layout is too complex that will probably look bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

However the drag and drop layout design method is not recommended for Android Applications UI designers but there is an Open Source project on Google Code:  **`android-ui-utils`** , in which you might find something intersiting.

It uses a Firefox addon `Pencil` to draw and design android layouts and also uses an online "Android Assets Studio" where you can design your custom Icons like:

- Launcher icons
- List item icons
- Menu Icons
- Notification icons

You can give up a try here:

http://code.google.com/p/android-ui-utils/

Comment: Can't seem to get pencil to work. Tried dragging the zips, as instructed, but won't work.

Answer (score 2):

DroidDraw is OK, but the reality is that if you are going to write for Android you are going to want to learn how to write XML layouts from scratch. I remember that XML layouts seemed bizarre when I first started working with the Android SDK, but eventually it starts to make sense.

I read a blog post from a member of the Android team at Google explaining why XML layouts are better than GUI-based layout systems (such as the one included with the iPhone SDK). I can't find the link right now, but basically XML allows for layouts that gracefully scale across devices of radically different sizes and purposes where a GUI-based layout designer often has to be tweaked at best and redone at worst for devices of different sizes.

Comment: Great point, Computersih. I have no problem writing XML from scratch. Just sometimes seems like you're doing boilerplate work that could be streamlined. I think I'm using DroidDraw better now actually. Just want to be able to like create a button real quick. Thanks all!

Comment: I agree about speed. I sometimes use the outline view provided in Eclipse. It is fairly quick to let create a Button for you. Then you can modify the XML manually for whatever parameters and positioning you need.

Answer (score 2):

The official Android Plugin for Eclipse comes with a GUI Editor which supports drag'n'drop of GUI Elements. Not necessarily better than DroidDraw, but maybe you didn't know yet: http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html