# Good Tools To Develop a GUI in Android?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I would like to know if there exists a good tool to implement a design in Android like tools to make easy to implement and that can generate XML

Thanks for your help.

Comment: similar here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300014/tools-for-rapid-layout-interface-creations/4300305#4300305

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [DroidDraw](http://www.droiddraw.org/) for better GUI layouts.

Comment: The current version of the ADT for Eclipse is better than Droiddraw already and no tool will be better than manual UI design.

Comment: +1 Nice link Cool Answer

Answer (score 9):

Yes there is the Eclipse AndroidDeveloperTools (ADT) plugin which has a pretty good GUI prototyping tool and there is the [Droiddraw](http://www.droiddraw.org/) project.

However none of them will ever replace manual UI design with XML or code.

Comment: +1 for "manual UI design with XML or code".

Answer (score 3):

The de facto tool for development in Android is Eclipse, which provides XML modelling tools as well